# Sql server 2017 Developer setup failed giving blank error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to install SQL server 2017 developer edition but when I launch the `setup.exe` the setup failed to start and returned a blank error message.

I tried the express edition and it gave the same result. I had checked the deletion of all previous version of sqls

[image]

Comment: have you executed the exe as administrator?

Comment: Where did you get those files? SQL Server 2017 Developer or Express editions are available as [web downloaders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads). Did you try the actual downloader? Did you try extracting the files from an `.iso` image or try to generate an offline install?

Comment: from where you have got those files ? try run as administrator

Comment: I'd say try running the actual web installer.

Comment: Please check the EventLog Viewer on your OS

Comment: yes I tried as administrator.

Comment: those files where created  in media SQL in c after I had installed it from Microsoft site the installation says that setup will be opened automatically after installation to see the installation plan stuff but the blank error message appeared and when I tried to press setup manually the same blank error message appers

Comment: you can see the error in the EventLog Viewer

Comment: where can I find the error event log for sql server

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved and the setup started when I tried to end all running tasks in task manager